# Transform with Binary Operation - G++ does not compile but VS does

Tags: c++, algorithm, compilation

The code below was a simple test I made to see if I could get transform to compile. The code compiles and correctly outputs this answer on visualstudio:

```
firsta
secondb
thirdc
```

But using g++ main.cpp -o main gives me these errors:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:19:106: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
main.cpp:19:107: error: no matching function for call to 'transform(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, main()::<lambda(const string&, const string&)>)'
main.cpp:19:107: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:4871:5: note: template<class _IIter, class _OIter, class _UnaryOperation> _OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:4907:5: note: template<class _IIter1, class _IIter2, class _OIter, class _BinaryOperation> _OIter std::transform(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _OIter, _BinaryOperation)

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> v, v2, v3;

    v.push_back("first"); v.push_back("second"); v.push_back("third");
    v2.push_back("a"); v2.push_back("b"); v2.push_back("c");
    v3.resize(3);


    transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v2.begin(), v3.begin(), [](const string &a, const string &b){return a + b;});
    copy(v3.begin(), v3.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this warning again:

```
main.cpp:19:106: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
```

To use C++11 features with GCC you need to use the option `-std=c++0x` if using GCC 4.6 or lower, and `-std=c++11` in version 4.7 or higher.

Comment: Yes, this worked. But I did read the warning before I posted this, particularly the portion that said, "[enabled by default]". I guess I'm sorry for trusting error messages.

Comment: @user904963 The "[enabled by default]" is about the warning, not about the option. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just what the compiler message says (**read it**):

> warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x

This compiles fine for me after adding the `-std=c++0x` flag.